# How to fix paint on existing draw

Tags: java, swing

I have some problems with my `DrawPanel`. I want to make a grill—that should be drawn with the parameters—given by the user by defining the rows and colons.

For example, I enter 3 rows and 5 colons (`:`), Swing should draw it. The main problem is if I enter the numbers in the `TextField` and press the draw button, Swing draws the new grill over the old one. Furthermore, sometimes the program doesn't complete some rows or colons and I don't understand why. I already add some numbers such as rows-6 because swing draw a few pixels more than he should. Probably you know a solution for this problem too.

On the picture you can see the lines that are to much. I use a blue line to show how far the lines should go.

[image]

#### DrawPanel (JPanel)

```java
import java.awt.Graphics;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Serge Junk
 */
public class DrawPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form DrawPanel
     * 
     */
    private int rows = 1;
    private int cols = 2;
    public DrawPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

         // draw the rows
        int rowHt = (height / rows)-1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++){
            g.drawLine(0, i * rowHt, width, i * rowHt);
        }


        // draw the columns
        int rowWid = (width / cols)-1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= cols; i++){
           g.drawLine(i * rowWid, 0, i * rowWid, height);
        }

    }

   public void setRows(int pRows){
       rows = pRows;
   }

    public void setCols(int pCols){
      cols = pCols;
   }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 200));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

#### MainFrame (JFrame)

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Serge Junk
 */
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainFrame
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void updateView()
    {
        drawPanel1.repaint();
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        drawPanel1 = new DrawPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        rowTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        colsTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        drawButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout drawPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(drawPanel1);
        drawPanel1.setLayout(drawPanel1Layout);
        drawPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            drawPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 600, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        drawPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            drawPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jLabel1.setText("Lignes");

        jLabel2.setText("Colonnes");

        drawButton.setText("Draw");
        drawButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                drawButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(rowTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(colsTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                        .addComponent(drawButton))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                        .addComponent(drawPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 600, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(26, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addComponent(drawPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 14, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(rowTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(colsTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(drawButton)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void drawButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        //E
        int row = Integer.valueOf(rowTextField.getText());
        int col = Integer.valueOf(colsTextField.getText());
        //T
        drawPanel1.setRows(row);
        drawPanel1.setCols(col);
        //S
        updateView();
    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField colsTextField;
    private javax.swing.JButton drawButton;
    private DrawPanel drawPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField rowTextField;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I want to add two comments. 1) Netbenas is an ide so this not paint, swing paint the component. 2) can you add the complete class inside the DrawPanel description?

Comment: I add the complete class inside the DrawPanel

Comment: also the class MainFrame is not complete

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this one. Now it is complete

Answer (score 1):

> Netbeans draw the new grill over the old one.

The first statement in the paintComponent() method should be:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

This will clear the background before you do your custom painting.

```
drawPanel1.setRows(row);
drawPanel1.setCols(col);
//S
updateView();
```

There is no need for the `updateView()` method. Instead both the `setRows(...)` and `setCols(...)` method should invoke `repaint()` directly. That is it is the responsibility of the component to repaint itself when a property of the component is changed.

> sometimes the program doesn't complete some rows or colons and I don't understand why.

```
int rowHt = height / rows-1;
```

Be explicit when using formulas so we know exactly what you intend instead of relying in the compiler. So you should use:

```
int rowHt = (height / rows) - 1;
```

Don't be afraid to create variables for your parameters:

```
//g.drawLine(i * rowWid, 0, i * rowWid, height-5);
int xOffset = i * rowWidth;
int yEnd = height - 5;
g.drawLine(xOffset, 0, xOffset, yEnd);
```

This then allows you to add debug code easily to see exactly what values a being used to draw the line:

```
System.out.println(xOffset + " : " + yEnd);
```

Now you should be able to determine if your logic is correct.

Comment: I tried using what you recommended. However, I cannot find a solution to my problem with the pixels that are too much. I added a picture (I didn't know that this work adding a picture) so that you and the others see my second issue

Comment: *I tried using what you recommended.* - no you haven't. *I cannot find a solution to my problem with the pixels that are too much*  - you still 1) are not using "(...)" around math operands. 2) haven't created variables with you math caculations 3) haven't added debug code to display the values of your math calculations. If you display the values (like panel width and the column width) it should be obvious why the lines are too long. The column width times the number of columns does not always fill the width of the panel, so you can't just use the width of the panel..

Answer (score 0):

So, as [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) suggested, you should not add any hidden variables to the division or rows / height or cols / width, because this is a maintenance nightmare. Stay away from magic values!

The `DrawPanel.paintComponent` must do a few things.

1. Don't forget to call `super()` !
2. You will need to determine line thickness so you know how much to offset.
3. Keep your units as floating-point values until you NEED to set them as integers.
4. Dispose afterwards.

Moreover, you do not want to set instance variables in their declaration, but through a constructor of some sorts.

Additionally, I added two more fields to control line width and color as seen below. I also redesigned the layout so that it is actually legible from a code maintenance standpoint.

[image]

[image]

#### Runner

```java
package question58310987;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new MainFrame();

                setLookAndFeel(frame);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void setLookAndFeel(JFrame frame) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

#### DrawPanel

```java
package question58310987;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1889951852010548809L;

    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private int thickness;
    private Color fgColor;
    private Color bgColor;

    private boolean dirty;
    private Stroke strokeRef;

    public DrawPanel() {
        this(3, 3);
    }

    public DrawPanel(int rows, int cols) {
        this(rows, cols, 1, Color.BLACK, null);
    }

    public DrawPanel(int rows, int cols, int thickness, Color fgColor, Color bgColor) {
        super();
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        this.thickness = thickness;
        this.fgColor = fgColor;
        this.bgColor = bgColor;

        this.dirty = true; // initialized as true
    }

    private float getStrokeThickness(Graphics2D g2d) {
        Stroke stroke = g2d.getStroke();

        if (stroke instanceof BasicStroke) {
            return ((BasicStroke) stroke).getLineWidth();
        }

        return 1.0f;
    }

    /**
     * Re-evaluates the state of the properties.
     */
    protected void commitProperties(Graphics2D g2d) {
        if (dirty) {
            strokeRef = new BasicStroke(this.thickness);
            dirty = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        commitProperties(g2d);

        g2d.setStroke(strokeRef);

        float lineSize = getStrokeThickness(g2d); // Calculate line thickness
        float halfStroke = lineSize > 2.0f ? lineSize / 2.0f : 1.0f;
        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();
        int maxWidth = (int) (width - halfStroke);
        int maxHeight = (int) (height - halfStroke);
        float yOffset = (((float) maxHeight - halfStroke) / (rows));
        float xOffset = (((float) maxWidth - halfStroke) / (cols));

        if (bgColor != null) {
            g2d.setColor(bgColor);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        g2d.setColor(fgColor);

        // Draw the horizontal lines
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            int y = (int) (row * yOffset + halfStroke);
            g2d.drawLine((int) halfStroke, y, maxWidth, y);
        }
        g2d.drawLine((int) halfStroke, maxHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight); // Draw the final horizontal line

        // Draw the vertical lines
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            int x = (int) (col * xOffset + halfStroke);
            g2d.drawLine(x, (int) halfStroke, x, maxHeight);
        }
        g2d.drawLine(maxWidth, (int) halfStroke, maxWidth, maxHeight); // Draw the final vertical line

        g2d.dispose(); // Clear changes
    }

    public String getFgColorHex() {
        return String.format("#%02X%02X%02X", fgColor.getRed(), fgColor.getGreen(), fgColor.getBlue());
    }

    public int getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(int rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public int getCols() {
        return cols;
    }

    public void setCols(int cols) {
        this.cols = cols;
    }

    public int getThickness() {
        return thickness;
    }

    public void setThickness(int thickness) {
        this.thickness = thickness;
        this.dirty = true;
    }

    public Color getFgColor() {
        return fgColor;
    }

    public void setFgColor(Color fgColor) {
        this.fgColor = fgColor;
    }

    public Color getBgColor() {
        return bgColor;
    }

    public void setBgColor(Color bgColor) {
        this.bgColor = bgColor;
    }
}
```

#### MainFrame

```java
package question58310987;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2796976952328960949L;
    private static final String DEFAULT_APP_TITLE = "Main Frame";

    private DrawPanel drawPanel;

    private JLabel rowLabel;
    private JTextField rowTextField;

    private JLabel colLabel;
    private JTextField colTextField;

    private JLabel thicknessLabel;
    private JTextField thicknessTextField;

    private JLabel colorLabel;
    private JTextField colorTextField;

    private JButton drawButton;

    public MainFrame() {
        this(DEFAULT_APP_TITLE);
    }

    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);

        initialize();
        addChildren();
    }

    protected void initialize() {
        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
        drawPanel.setThickness(6);
        drawPanel.setFgColor(Color.BLUE);
        drawPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));

        rowLabel = new JLabel("Rows");
        rowTextField = new JTextField(Integer.toString(drawPanel.getRows()), 3);

        colLabel = new JLabel("Columns");
        colTextField = new JTextField(Integer.toString(drawPanel.getCols()), 3);

        thicknessLabel = new JLabel("Thickness");
        thicknessTextField = new JTextField(Integer.toString(drawPanel.getThickness()), 3);

        colorLabel = new JLabel("Color");
        colorTextField = new JTextField(drawPanel.getFgColorHex(), 6);

        drawButton = new JButton("Draw");
        drawButton.addActionListener(evt -> drawButtonActionPerformed(evt));
    }

    protected void addChildren() {
        GridBagLayout verticalLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(16, 16, 16, 16); // top, left, bottom, right

        getContentPane().setLayout(verticalLayout);
        getContentPane().add(drawPanel, gbc);

        FlowLayout horizontalLayout = new FlowLayout();
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(horizontalLayout);

        buttonPanel.add(rowLabel);
        buttonPanel.add(rowTextField);
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));

        buttonPanel.add(colLabel);
        buttonPanel.add(colTextField);
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));

        buttonPanel.add(thicknessLabel);
        buttonPanel.add(thicknessTextField);
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));

        buttonPanel.add(colorLabel);
        buttonPanel.add(colorTextField);
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));

        buttonPanel.add(drawButton);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 16, 16, 16); // top, left, bottom, right

        getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, gbc);
    }

    private void drawButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        int row = Integer.valueOf(rowTextField.getText().trim());
        int col = Integer.valueOf(colTextField.getText().trim());
        int thickness = Integer.valueOf(thicknessTextField.getText().trim());
        String colorHex = colorTextField.getText().trim();

        drawPanel.setRows(row);
        drawPanel.setCols(col);
        drawPanel.setThickness(thickness);
        drawPanel.setFgColor(hexToColor(colorHex));

        this.updateView();
    }

    public void updateView() {
        drawPanel.repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Supports both #FF0000 and #F00 formats.
     * 
     * @param hex a hexadecimal color value from #000000 -> #FFFFFF
     * @return
     */
    public static final Color hexToColor(String hex) {
        if (hex.startsWith("#")) {
            hex = hex.replace("#", "");
        }
        if (hex.length() == 3) {
            hex = splicePad(hex, 2);
        }
        int v = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
        int r = (v & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
        int g = (v & 0xFF00) >> 8;
        int b = (v & 0xFF);
        return new Color(r, g, b);
    }

    /**
     * Splices each character after itself n-number of times. 
     */
    public static final String splicePad(String str, final int repeat) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

        for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
                buff.append(ch);
            }
        }

        return buff.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But is this more a formal way, so that it looks better? However, I have still the same problem with the lignes that are too long.

Comment: @DizzySailor I didn't see that when I ran the program, but you just subtract the n+1 pixels from the resulting length... I will update.